# Laravel - Routing with Inertia Visit to fill prop in Vuejs3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3, inertiajs

I want to send data from `page A` to `page B` without use controllers, just in laravel routes. ( Laravel / VueJS3 / InertiaJS )

In my first page, I have this method:

```js
// first.vue
tappedCourse(course: Course): void {
    const data: secondParams = {
        courseName: course.name,
    };
    Inertia.get("/second", data as any);
},
```

And in my route:

```php
// web.php
Route::inertia('/second', 'Course/Second');
```

Finally my second page prop:

```js
// second.vue
export default defineComponent({
props: {
    courseName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "",
    },
},
```

The problem is the second page prop doesn't receive the value, but if I manually insert:

```php
// web.php
Route::inertia('/second', 'Course/Second', [
    "couseName" => "Inertia + Laravel"
]);
```

It's working fine.

Have some way to can I get the 'query param' in my route? like `$courseName` and send to my `second.vue` like code above.

Note: The `inertia.get` is working because I receive in URL the param name: value.

```
http://localhost:8000/second?name="Inertia + Laravel"
```

Note 2: My preference would be if it was a POST, but I didn't find in the documentation how to do it with laravel route ( Route::inertia ).

Answer (score 0):

`Route::inertia` only handles `GET` and `HEAD` requests. Try this:

```php
Route::post('/second', function ($courseName) {
   return Inertia::render('Course/Second', compact('courseName'));
});
```